# What is a chef provider and how do I know which provider will chef use?

Tags: chef-infra

I don't even find any official documentations for provider.
How does chef decide which provider to use for a particular action (say, for the `enable` action for service) ?
What's the default?
How do I check or change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provider is not picked for specific action, it is chosen for the whole resource.

When you write your own custom resources there are specificity rules, I think it also applies to chef-provided resources, not only the custom ones. Also, you can override the provider, if you want..

Also in most of the cases, you can call specific provider instead of a generic one, for example, `apt_package` instead of `package`. Same thing applies to the services or any other resource. Although, Chef is quite good at figuring out what suits the system best (in most of the cases, as I have mentioned)